# Почему метод, реализующий интерфейс, не может возвращать дочерний объект?

Tags: c#

Допустим есть класс *А*, реализующий  интерфейс *I*.

```
interface I { }
class A : I { }
```

Теперь сделаем интерфейс с функцией *foo*, возвращающей *I*.

```
interface IGetter
{
    I foo();
}
```

И попытаемся его реализовать.

```
class Getter : IGetter
{
    public A foo()
    {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

На что получим ошибку компиляции мол «класс *Getter* не реализует интерфейс *IGetter*». И пойдём писать явную реализацию интерфейса, являющуюся обёрткой вызова *foo()*.

```
I IGetter.foo()
{
    return foo();
}
```

Но зачем это? С какой целью стандарты не разрешают в качестве возвращаемого типа иметь тип, неявно преобразующийся к исходному?

**UPD:** вопрос сугубо о причине описанного запрета. Пожалуйста, не предлагайте способы его обойти, их я и сам могу придумать с десяток.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> С какой целью стандарты не разрешают в качестве возвращаемого типа иметь тип, неявно преобразующийся к исходному?

С целью запрета ковариации и контрвариации для переопределений методов и реализаций интерфейсов. Более подробно описано в книге C# in Depth(2-е издание), подраздел 2.2.2. "Нехватка ковариантных типов возвращаемого значения".

Comment: Хорошая статья по этому поводу: http://blog.t-l-k.com/dot-net/2009/c-sharp-4-covariance-and-contravariance

Answer (score 3):

А как насчёт

```
public I foo()
{
  return new A();
}
```

?

Comment: +1, просто неверная сигнатура метода при реализации. Либо поменять в интерфейсе тип на А, либо сделать, как написано тут.

Comment: Если класс A, как в моём утрированном примере, ничем не расширяет интерфейс, то хорошо. Но в реальной жизни он имеет много добавочного функционала терять который нельзя.

Comment: если вам нужен добавочный функционал, то может стоит дополнить соответсвующий интефейс или реализовать другой

Comment: Абсолютно не понял ваш коммент. Мое замечание относилось только к синтаксису, а вообще конечно лучше работать с более общими типами (интерфейс в вашем случае), чем конкретными реализациями. 3й принцип СОЛИД

Comment: @wind, ещё раз: менять в интерфейсе тип на A нельзя потому, что тогда его не смогут реализовать классы, имеющие возращаемым значением тип B, реализующий I. Делать как в ответе тоже нельзя потому, что класс А имеет кучу других методов, терять которые нельзя.

Comment: Вопрос об архитектуре, как я пытался намекнуть выше, здесь не рассматривается, но все это в рамках синтаксиса с# будет работать!

Comment: @wind, спасибо. Щас допишу уточнение к вопросу.